# $meteor.collection doesn't return a Collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

Following the [Angular-Meteor tutorial step 9](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_09), I'm trying to create an Angular directive that uses a Meteor collection.

This file is in the root folder:

```
TicTacToeBoards = new Meteor.Collection("tic_tac_toe_boards");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('TicTacToeBoards', function() { return TicTacToeBoards.find(); });
}
```

This file is in the /client folder:

```
angular.module('TicTacToe').directive('tictactoegraph', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'client/graph/tictactoegraph.ng.html',
        scope: true,
        controller: function($scope, $meteor, Sigma, TicTacToeClass) {
            $scope.TicTacToeBoards = false;

            $meteor.subscribe('TicTacToeBoards').then(function(subscriptionHandle){
                $scope.TicTacToeBoards = $meteor.collection(TicTacToeBoards);
            });
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            // TODO: Ask SO if there's a better way to wait on the subscription....
            $scope.$watch('TicTacToeBoards', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if ($scope.TicTacToeBoards) {
                    console.log($scope.TicTacToeBoards); // An array of objects.
                    var nextBoards = $scope.TicTacToeBoards.find({ numberOfMoves: 0 });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it gives an error:

> TypeError: $scope.TicTacToeBoards.find is not a function

It appears that `$scope.TicTacToeBoards` is not a Mongo cursor, but is the array of objects that TicTacToeBoards.find() would return. Why isn't it a cursor?

Comment: Jesus Christ! Why do you people need angular in meteor?

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable. A lot of people like Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $meteor.collection doesn't return a cursor, it returns an array of type AngularMeteorCollection which is different:
http://angular-meteor.com/api/AngularMeteorCollection

It does that because we wanted to give Angular developers a regular array with ll it's API to work easily with.

It's an interesting idea to add a `find` function to that array though.
Do want want to use that function to return a filtered object?
You could use filters for that, but maybe we can add this option as well